# How can I calculate fees for my smart accounts and smart assets?

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts, wavesplatform, ride

I'm writing a smart contract via Waves and I need to include the correct fees for that, how to make the calculation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each time the script is called, total transaction fee increases by 0.004 Waves.
For example, If you will transfer smart assets from scripted account the final fee is 0.009.WAVES. Calculation of the fee will be as follows 0.001+0.004+0.004=0.009 WAVES. Where 0.001 WAVES for simple transfer transaction, 0.004 WAVES for transfer smart asset and additional 0.004 WAVES for transfer from smart account.
You can check [the fees for all transactions](https://docs.wavesplatform.com/en/waves-environment/waves-protocol/transactions-fees.html).